# Are links in canvas/WebGL with a sitemap good enough for SEO, or do I need normal a href links too?

Tags: seo, sitemap, single-page-application

The main page of my site is comprised of big graphics and animations implemented with Canvas/WebGL using pixi.js library. The problem is all links are also implemented as interaction with WebGL layer.

But then I know I can just list my links in sitemap.xml. Is listing the links in sitemap enough for good SEO in this situation?

Or should I somehow check something and insert normal `a` instead?

Comment: Are you using HTML5 .html page? Because the last time i did some work with WebGL i used a HTML5 and connect the sitemap to meta tag headers.

Comment: @jehovahsays Yes, I am. Which meta tag was it?

Comment: Search keyword Robots meta tag and X-Robots-Tag HTTP header specifications & decide which you need.                                                   And then tell search engines or other robots where your sitemap is located. For example the complete robots.txt could look like this:

User-agent: *
Disallow:

SITEMAP: http://www.example.com/sitemap.txt

Comment: @jehovahsays Yes, I know how to make a sitemap.xml. But I do not know if it's enough. Some people say that if site is not crawlable then sitemap.xml isn't enough. On the other hand "cloaking" links might get me banned.

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you https://moz.com/blog/javascript-seo

Comment: "if site is not crawlable then sitemap.xml isn't enough" - Well, the main reason for having an XML sitemap in the first place is for when the site is hard to crawl. An XML sitemap simply allows search engines to discover URLs. If a site is easy to crawl then you arguably don't _need_ an XML sitemap.

Comment: @MrWhite The way that web-masters regard sitemap.xml is really just a religious ritual without any real meaning. They always generate sitemaps using a crawler to be used by another crawler. Tags `lastmod`, `changefreq` and `priority` are just pure lies. And they do not worry about any contradictions between sitemap and robots.txt `disallow` sentences. When I ask seo-professionals about these things they say that they are not to be thought about but they are to be known by all. Just do it, it's seo. Information about sitemap is full of contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by saying I don't know the answer to this. But it is a truism in SEO that we favour href links and it is also true that Google (and other search engines) are getting better at indexing content that doesn't use href links.

If it were me I would build some test pages and see if these types of links get crawled (I would actually be interested to know too).

You could use something like Google Search Console (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) to let Google know the pages exist and see how they get crawled. You could also use a tool like Screaming Frog (https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) to test the setup.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'll try it when I go back to this problem

Comment: Let me know how it goes or if you need any help with the tools I mentioned, I'd be happy to know how it goes.

Comment: The project did not and never will reach production state. It was abandoned. So I will not know how it goes.