# If you can place hidden text and HTML on page for SEO in white hat case

Tags: seo

Say you have your website built all in WebGL or SVG. All your text is in there like that too. I'm wondering, then, if you could put duplicate text in HTML but just make it invisible. So you would have the same text in both WebGL and HTML. This would be purely for SEO purposes. Wondering if this is acceptable.

It used to be this is what you'd have to do with Flash websites, so I'm wondering how it is today.

Comment: The first thing you learn in web site development is to never, EVER do this as it will be the first step to getting your site blacklisted by everyone and every thing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering) about web rendering engine, is WebGL not supported by the indexer. So you can no worry - your WebGL content will be not indexed.

With the Flash websites there was an opposite problem - developer wanted to index their content, containing in the Flash objects, but Google wasn't able to. There was the cause to create workarounds to make a HTML/XML fallbacks to export textual content from outta Flash objects.

Comment: I would like my WebGL content indexed

Comment: why do you want to index WebGL content, and not HTML?

Comment: I want to draw my text in WebGL, instead of HTML, so I can animate each individual character.

Comment: Css3 isn't for you? It let's animate pretty good.

Comment: Beside the point :)

Comment: here is something similar https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/112554/43910, but - no, i see no real possibility to index WebGL content.